# launching lotus notes from javascript

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

Any idea how to launch lotus notes from javascript and attach a document to a new mail programmatically. I know many will find it absurd.. but my stake holders seem to have a fascination with impossible feats!

could it be done via an xPage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually extend the mailto url abit and get a subject, body text and an attachment too

> ```
> mailto:someone@example.com?subject=my new email&body=attachment below&attachment=c:\temp\thefile.txt
> ```

The attachment must be stored on a drive that the machine can access it's not and url.
And you might need double slashes.

Answer (score 3):

If Lotus Notes is the default mail client (which it usually is if its an enterprise environment), then all you need to do is create a [`mailto:` link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

For example:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

This can be customised to include a subject or a body, and when clicked in a webpage will launch the default mail client and which should then populate form.

Comment: It was That simple? I'm astounded! :O

Comment: In fact, that does not attach a document ;-) Other option is to use notes url (notes://)